# Joda time: Invalid format

Tags: java, jodatime

I am using Joda API to format current time (the result must be a string formatted as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"). Below I provide my code and the error message:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
String datetime = dtf.parseDateTime(dt.toString()).toString();
```

Error message:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format:
>   "2014-11-17T11:47:29.229+01:00" is malformed at "T11:47:29.229+01:00"
>     at
>   org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:899)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert to string using a custom format do

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
String datetime = dtf.print(dt);
```

What you're currently doing in the last line is

```
String defaultFormatted = dt.toString();
// this is what contains the "T11:47:29.229+01:00" part

DateTime dateTime = dtf.parseDateTime(defaultFormatted);
// we're back at the beginning, this is equivalent to your original "dt"

String defaultFormattedAgain = dateTime.toString();
// and this is the same as the initial string with T11:..
```

So you're converting to & from string several times but never using `dtf` to actually format how the string should look like.

Answer (score 3):

The default DateTime string representation needs a different pattern:

```
   DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+01:00'");
```

If you want to format the date with your pattern you need to use the print() method:

```
   DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   DateTime dt = new DateTime();
   String datetime = dtf.print(dt);
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I generate the current date and time, and then format it as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"?